# Gutenberg block variation remove alignment from toolbar

Tags: reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm duplicating the image block by using `registerBlockVariation`

```
registerBlockVariation( 'core/image', {
  name: 'image-custom',
  title: 'Image Custom',
  attributes: {
    myAttribute: 'custom'
  },
  supports: {
    align: false
  }
} );
```

This creates a new block called "Image Custom" with all the properties of the core image block. However I want to remove the alignment options from it. I tried `supports: { align: false }` but it does not work.

Note: I do not want to change the core image block. I need to duplicate it as I did but remove alignment.

How can I do this? Maybe there's another way besides `registerBlockVariation`?

Answer (score 0):

[registerBlockVariation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-variations/) doesn't support changing supports properties of its 'Source Block'. So in your case, you have to create your own custom block with registerBlockType. [This tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/learning-gutenberg-7-building-our-block-custom-card-block/) can help you if you need to remodel the core/image block. Just leave out unwanted code, add your own supports values, and you're good to go.